# Resultset automatically close itself and showing error Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, multiple-resultsets

Getting Exception

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

```
<%
ResultSet rs=null,rs1=null;
Statement stmt=null,stmt1=null;
String UserID = request.getParameter("UserID"); 
String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
session.setAttribute("UserID",UserID);
int flag=0;
try{    
    System.out.println("Validating..1");
    //stmt =  con.createStatement();
    //stmt1 =  con.createStatement();

    String Query = "select * from login where UserID = '"+UserID+"' and Password='"+Password+"'";
    System.out.println(Query);
    rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
    System.out.println(rs);
    if(rs!=null)
    {
        String Query1="Select * from basicdetails where UserID='"+UserID+"' and Password='"+Password+"'";
        System.out.println(Query1);
        rs1=st.executeQuery(Query1);
        //System.out.println(rs1);
        if(!rs1.next())
        {
            System.out.println("RS1");
            while(rs1.next())
            {
                String PhotoPath=rs1.getString(4);
                System.out.println("-------------------"+PhotoPath);
                session.setAttribute("PhotoPath",PhotoPath);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!rs.next())
    {
        String Auth=rs.getString(3);
        session.setAttribute("Auth",new Integer(Auth));
        flag=1;
        if(Auth.equals("0"))
        {
            //Show Admin Menu
        %>
        <jsp:forward page="AdminMenu.jsp"/>
    <%
    }
        else if(Auth.equals("1"))
        {
            //Show user Menu
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="UserHome.jsp"/>
    <%
    }
    }
    else
    {
        flag=0;
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="Login.jsp"/>
    <%
    }
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
                        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                        System.out.println(e.getClass());
            %><%=e%><%
        }

%>
```

And Here is the message shown in output window of Netbeans

> Validating..1 select * from login where UserID = 'admin' and
>   Password='admin' com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@b2c1e7 Select * from
>   basicdetails where UserID='admin' and Password='admin' RS1 null
>   [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1d8608c class java.sql.SQLException

What is the issue with the above code which is .jsp file trying to validate login credential of admin and other users.

Comment: The glaring problem is java code inside a jsp. Try refactoring to use tag libraries or jstl expressions and it might get easier to debug

Comment: `stmt.close();` also closes the `ResultSet`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Even if I delete both the last 2 line `stmt.close();` and `con.close();` still getting same error

Comment: Master password: `' OR 1=1 --`. You need to switch to using [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Every body is mentioning their own views no one clearing my doubt. Simply I'm asking Why rs1 close by itself what is the reason. I am not asking for solution

Comment: You were given the reason an hour before you wrote that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the whole code which I posted in my question, after getting answers from you all experts. We as a beginner expect your right guidance and proper clarification that's all. Here is the code -

```
<%
ResultSet rs=null,rs1=null;

    String UserID = request.getParameter("UserID"); 
    String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
    session.setAttribute("UserID",UserID);
    int flag=0;
    try{    
        System.out.println("Validating..1");
        int Auth=1,flag1 = 0;

        String Query = "select * from login where UserID = '"+UserID+"' and Password='"+Password+"'";
        String Que = "select * from basicdetails where userid='"+UserID+"' and password='"+Password+"';";
        System.out.println(Que);
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            if(UserID.equals(rs.getString(1)) && Password.equals(rs.getString(2)))
            {
               Auth=rs.getInt(3);
               session.setAttribute("Auth",new Integer(Auth));
            }
            i++;
        }
        rs.close();

        if(i>0)
        {
         System.out.println("I " + i);
            if(Auth==1)
            {
                System.out.println("USER Verification");
            rs1= st.executeQuery(Que);
            System.out.println(rs1);
            rs1.next();
            String PhotoPath=rs1.getString(4);
            System.out.println("-------------------"+PhotoPath);
            session.setAttribute("PhotoPath",PhotoPath);
            %>
                <jsp:forward page="UserHome.jsp"/>
            <%
            }
            else if(Auth==0)
            {
            %>
                <jsp:forward page="AdminMenu.jsp"/>
            <%
            }
        }
        else
        {
            %>
            <jsp:forward page="Login.jsp"/>
            <%
        }        
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    %>
      <%=e%>
    <% } %>
```

Thank you everybody, and sorry for little harsh. Thank you again.

Comment: The user ID and password are already equal to the supplied parameters, by the terms of the query. You don't need to test them again. You can't ignore the result of `ResultSet.next().`  You still haven't explained why you have the password column in two tables.

Comment: @EJP UserID is Primary key in both the table, I tried to use join in SQL and successfully done also for but for admin login ONLY join doesn't work, because admin login detail is not in basicdetails table. So for users join works fine, but for admin join query fail. Here is the query `String Query = "select l.UserID,l.Password,l.Auth,b.UserID,b.Password,b.PhotoPath from login l,basicdetail b where l.UserID = '"+UserID+"' and l.Password='"+Password+"' and l.UserID = b.UserID;` this is fine for user in basicdetail table but for admin this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `ResultSet.next()` after it has already returned false.

This code doesn't make any sense. You are checking `rs == null` where it cannot be null. `ResultSets` returned by `executeQuery()` cannot be null. You could do the whole thing with a single query and a join. Why you would have a password field in two tables is a mystery, or else the second query is a bug.

Comment: Why rs cannot be null if id & password is wrong then rs will be null

Comment: The result set would be _empty_, not `null`, if the query returned no rows.

Comment: Ok fine rs cannot be null, then is there any way to check whether rs is empty or not?

Comment: Seriously? Have you read the Javadoc? `ResultSet.next()` returns false when there are no more rows. If there are zero rows it returns false the first time you call it.

Comment: @EJP Thank you EJP atleast you mentioned the reason, but I got the answer by reading Java Doc yesterday only and I issued the problem.

Comment: You got the answer which I had already mentioned by reading the Javadoc which you should have already done before you posted the question, and you stated here that nobody gave you the reason, which is false.